# Possible reasons for skipped numbers in names of drive partitions

Tags: partitioning

Upon running `sudo lsblk` I discovered that the partitions on one of my drives are numbered as 1, 2, 5, 6. What could have happened to 3 and 4?

The drive started out as data drive with Ubuntu later installed.

Partial `lsblk` output:

```
NAME     SIZE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    465.8G disk 
├─sdb1 390.8G part 
├─sdb2     1K part 
├─sdb5  71.1G part /
└─sdb6   3.9G part [SWAP]
```

Output of `sudo parted /dev/sdb print`:

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG HD502IJ (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      33.3kB  420GB  420GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      420GB   500GB  80.5GB  extended
 5      420GB   496GB  76.4GB  logical   ext4
 6      496GB   500GB  4149MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Given the `parted` output, steeldriver's supposition is correct. I'll add, though, that primary partitions can have gaps in their numbering. They work sort of like Post Office boxes; the numbers don't change when one goes vacant. The same is true of the newer GPT partitions. Logical partitions, though, take on contiguous numbers starting with 5, so you won't normally see gaps in logical partition numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)-based partition schemes can only have a maximum of four [primary partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Primary_partition), Linux installers typically 'play nice' by making use of an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition), which uses up only one primary (in your case, `sdb2`, since `sda1` is already allocated to the NTFS partition). The required root (`/`) and `swap` partitions are then created as `sdb5` and `sdb6` *logical partitions* within `sdb2`, leaving `sdb3` and `sdb4` available for other OSes to use in subsequent installations.

Newer partitioning schemes such as [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) don't have the same limitations and don't need the extended partitions as a workaround.